# Example for Java Spring Microservice with MOM

Tags: java, spring, rest, rabbitmq

i am interested in microservice architecure. I can find a lot of tutorials for Spring REST, Spring Boot and RabbitMQ etc. But i would like to see a full example which ist more complex and combining all the techniques.
Does someone now such an example source code?

thx

Answer (score 1):

There are several tutorials / videos from [Josh Long](https://twitter.com/starbuxman) who tries to show some "enhanced" examples of what you can do with Microservices in Spring Boot. I'd refer to his ["Bootiful Microservices"](https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-microservices) on Github. This combines a lot of the techniques the [Spring Cloud suite](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) offers for implementing Microservices.